# Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'languages/Array.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/')

Tags: php

I posting link here :
project website 
http://www.stolarstvofatura.sk/

I got on the top ofindex page php tags

I checked the path and everything.. everything is okay i dont know where is problem

This is on index page -

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';
?>
```

This is on config page which is on same dir like index

```
<?php  
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "sk";
} else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != 
$_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang']) ) {
    if ($_GET['lang'] == "sk") {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "sk";
    } else if($_GET['lang'] == "en") {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    }
}

require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
?>
```

I expected no errors

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['lang']);` contain?

Comment: its saying NULL

Comment: where is the `languages` directory in the folder heirarchy?

Comment: @aynber view-source:http://www.stolarstvofatura.sk/config.php ... var dumb is saying this

Comment: @RamRaider its on the root folder

Comment: @codeHysteria your else part is missing, It might not reaching any condition, please set by default language to $_SESSION['lang'] after session_start(); and then check

Comment: and yet if you use the querystring , such as `http://www.stolarstvofatura.sk/config.php?lang=en` you get info - or `http://www.stolarstvofatura.sk/config.php?lang=sk`

Comment: @suhaspandit i set $_SESSION['lang'] = to "sk" by default and its working now thanks for your help. but there is another think.... when i click for example on about us it always changes automaticly to default= "sk" and i dont want it like that

Comment: please help me ... :(

Comment: @codeHysteria for that you need to refactor your conditions as per your requirement.

Comment: i was doing same project 2 weeks ago with same thing everything is working there... here none

Comment: help pleaaaaasee

Comment: @codeHysteria you need to debug conditions, and set else condition so that you definitely will have some value in  $_SESSION['lang']

Comment: but you know i used the same code that is working on other website...

Comment: please i tried everything and its still not working...

Comment: @suhaspandit any sugestions please ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably simplify the logic used to select the language and, so long as yu start the session at the beginning of each page ( as here ) then clicking "about us" or whatever should not affect the language chosen.

```
<?php 

    /* config.php */
    session_start();


    $qvar='lang';
    $svar='language';

    $default='sk';
    $languages=array('en','sk','de'); # 3 language options


    if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) )$_SESSION[ $svar ]=$default;
    if( isset( $_GET[ $qvar ] ) && in_array( strtolower( $_GET[ $qvar ] ), $languages ) ) $_SESSION[ $svar ]=strtolower( $_GET[ $qvar ] );



    $languagefile = sprintf( '%s/languages/%s.php', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
    require realpath( $languagefile );

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195513/discussion-on-answer-by-ramraider-fatal-error-require-once-function-require).